# close pyqt4 window automatically

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have a python code that create a message box with PyQt4. some lines of my code is:

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clear_win)
```

When I clicked the button, the window closed.

Now, I want to close it automatically. I mean when the window(mssage box) apears, it can close after some seconds and doesn't need to push the button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a timer and call `self.clear_win` when the timer expires.

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clear_win)

    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.clear_win)
```

Comment: I don't want use `self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clear_win)`, and also this code doesn't work for me.thanks.

Comment: You can remove the button altogether, I just left it in. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Now I removed it, but it doesn't close the window!

Comment: In clear_win I called another function, but it depends on click event. I don't know if I can simulate click in python.

Answer (score -1):

Actually we use `sys.exec_()` function at the end of the pyqt application this is where everything goes wrong... self.close() closes the dialog but not the application. `sys.exec_(`) will accept something to do manually or accepts the close button click. if you remove that, then application will not be shown to you or it will close automatically. if you want to close the app after sometime... then you can use sleep(5) and the `self.exec_()` will close your app automatically.

Comment: It is never advisable to use sleep in the GUI thread, there are other options like QEventLoop with QTimer